# Where is the official documentation on google+ comments?

Tags: web, comments, google-plus, google-search-console

I've found a few examples about how to insert google+ comments at some site, but I cann't find any official documentation about this. Please help me find it. I need to know about width settings

Comment: Look at the api docs for g+. also include relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any. The Google+ Comments widget is not a public API and only officially supports use within Google's own apps (Blogger, YouTube).